# The text rendering with LaTex met problem for Cartopy-based longitude, latitude in Python 2.7

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

In Python Matplotlib, it is easy to use LaTeX to manage all text layout. However, it could not work corrected with Cartopy, a geographical data visualization tool.

Here is an example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy as np   

from matplotlib import rc 
rc('text', usetex=True)


extent=(97, 109, 25.5,35)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(25,40,5), crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(98,110,4), crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())  
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(LongitudeFormatter())
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(LatitudeFormatter())   
ax.set_extent(extents=extent, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

Error shows like:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb0' in position 230: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How to fix this issue. I thought it might be related with the symbol "oN", "oE".

Comment: Can you perhaps try adding the following two lines in the beginning and re-running the code? `from matplotlib import rc` and `rc('text', usetex=True)`

Comment: Sorry, I missed those two lines in the question. Indeed, rc option was called, and led to that error.